# python datetime relativedelta gives different values

Tags: python, timedelta, python-dateutil

I have the following code to get a Friday always later than the base date.

```
def get_next_settlement_date(base_date):
    settlement_date = base_date + relativedelta(days=1, weekday=FR)
```

I have the following unit test:

```
for i in range(7):
    base_date = localtime(now() + timedelta(days=i))
    settlement_date = Settlement.objects.next_settlement_date(base_date)
    logger.debug("{} - {}".format(base_date, settlement_date))
    self.assertTrue(settlement_date > localtime(now()), '{} > {}'.format(settlement_date, localtime(now())))
    self.assertTrue(settlement_date > base_date)
```

When my colleague ran it, it got an error:

```
self.assertTrue(settlement_date > localtime(now()), '{} > {}'.format(settlement_date, localtime(now())))
AssertionError: 2015-02-20 00:00:00+13:00 > 2015-02-20 12:13:34.954536+13:00
```

The error is saying that base on `2015-02-20 12:13:34.954536+13:00` the settlement date is `2015-02-20 00:00:00+13:00`

When I ran the test, it went fine, so I tried to mimic the same date time when my colleague ran it:

```
for i in range(7):
    import pytz
    from datetime import datetime

    auckland = pytz.timezone('Pacific/Auckland')
    base_date = auckland.localize(datetime.strptime('2015-02-20 12:13:34.954536', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') + timedelta(days=i))
    # base_date = localtime(now() + timedelta(days=i))
    settlement_date = Settlement.objects.next_settlement_date(base_date)
    logger.debug("{} - {}".format(base_date, settlement_date))
    self.assertTrue(settlement_date > localtime(now()), '{} > {}'.format(settlement_date, localtime(now())))
    self.assertTrue(settlement_date > base_date)
```

The unittest passed and base on `2015-02-20 12:13:34.954536+13:00` generated settlement date is `2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00`

Output:

```
2015-02-20 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
2015-02-21 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
2015-02-22 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
2015-02-23 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
2015-02-24 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
2015-02-25 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
2015-02-26 12:13:34.954536+13:00 - 2015-02-27 00:00:00+13:00
```

I am struggling to understand why it generated the wrong settlement date for my colleague at that point in time.

Comment: If both of you run `localtime(now() + timedelta(days=i))` on your respective machines, do you get the same output ?

Comment: we ran the modified unittest again on our machines, and both got the correct settlement date...

Comment: have you tried to reset the clock and set the timezone globally (for the python process) so that `time.time()`, `time.mktime()`, `time.localtime()` would return values corresponding to `'Pacific/Auckland'` and `2015-02-20 12:13`? It seems some part of the system has used UTC as local time or in reverse (utc date != local date).